# Need help in finding limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

I have solved the limit of an expression like this.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkEBI.jpg)

But the answer is **1/2** by using **L Hospital rule**. Why am I wrong?

Comment: In the second-to-last transition you "can" (no) also say that $\lim_{x \to 0} 1+x = 1$, and then your answer will be $0$.

Comment: Better to use MathJax to render the math. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pieces of a function in a limit have to go to their limits together.  When you replace $\ln(1+x)/x$ by $1$, then you're letting one bit run on ahead of the other bits.  You don't get to do this:

$$e = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = \lim_{x \to \infty} 1^x = 1.$$

Both occurences of $x$ have to go to infinity at the same time.

Comment: Yes thanks. I forgot about the algebraic rules of limits ie. Individual limits should exist for that step to be correct. I realised it later. Which is why LH rule is the only way to solve that problem. Thanks for the answer!!